# bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying get a api from runrunit, I saw some tutorials about requests and i got some problems in my code

> bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>

I didn't find anywhere, maybe is simple, but not for me

```
import requests, json

appkey = '****'
usertoken = '****'
contenttype = 'application/json'
charset = 'utf-8'
contentlength = '4443'

headers = {'App-Key' : appkey,'User-Token' : usertoken,'Content-Type' : contenttype,'charset' : charset, 'Content-Length' : contentlength}

url_base = 'https://runrun.it/api/v1.0/users'

response = requests.get(url_base, headers=headers)
print(response.json)
```

Comment: Did you consider _calling_ that method? What's the _question_?

Comment: can you explained in a dumb way for me ?

Comment: Use `response.json()` with the parentheses.  It's a function, so you have to _call_ it.

Comment: However, after correcting that, you'll run into a different error, since the response status is `400`. That means there is probably something wrong with your headers. Maybe try with just `App-Key` and `User-Token`?